# Spring managed transactions, EclipseLink JPA, custom isolation level

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, eclipselink

I suspect this one is embarrassing an I am doing it wrong in a terrible way, but please bear with me.

I have a Spring application with Spring-managed transactions.
It uses EclipseLink JPA.
I have a method which does a `findByNativeQuery()` followed by a `merge()`.  I need this to happen in a real SERIAL transaction isolation level. 
I tried adding 
`@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)`

This doesn't work because `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect#beginTransaction` 
does not support any transaction isolation level but the default.
So then I tried getting to UnitOfWork internals of ElcipseLink and starting/comitting my own transactions, but then I get an error:

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException : Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead
```

Which of course makes sense... but what do I do??

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-change-transaction-isolation-level-example). I haven't tried it myself, but looks like a good place to start.

Comment: I think JPA does not support custom isolation levels. This is a limitation of JPA, not Spring. It might require to implement Custom JpaDialect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've given a try to this, but I am not completely sure of the solution. I've taken the code from [this blog](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-change-transaction-isolation-level-example) and adapted it for EclipseLink. Here's the code:

```
package com.byteslounge.spring.tx.dialect;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;

import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.UnitOfWork;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException;

public class CustomEclipseLinkJpaDialect extends EclipseLinkJpaDialect {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean lazyDatabaseTransaction = false;

    @Override
    public void setLazyDatabaseTransaction(boolean lazyDatabaseTransaction) {
        this.lazyDatabaseTransaction = lazyDatabaseTransaction;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beginTransaction(final EntityManager entityManager,
            final TransactionDefinition definition)
            throws PersistenceException, SQLException, TransactionException {

        UnitOfWork uow = (UnitOfWork) getSession(entityManager);
        uow.getLogin().setTransactionIsolation(definition.getIsolationLevel());

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        if (!definition.isReadOnly() && !lazyDatabaseTransaction) {
            uow.beginEarlyTransaction();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm seeing the SERIALIZABLE isolation being logged when the transaction is initiated, but this needs to be tested properly to confirm it works.

Comment: I've debugged my code and got into `JpaTransactionManager.doBegin()` method and inspected the `ConnectionHandle` it is being obtained to look for the actual MySQL `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection` instance. The actual connection that is used actually DOES use the isolation level set for that method (javax.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE).

Comment: We haven't had time to test it but I figure I would give bounty as this is the only answer with significant effort put into it.  Future reader beware -- this accepted answer has not yet been evaluated for correctness.

Comment: I gave a shot at this. Please educate me.. will it be applicable, with a transaction definition as PROPAGATION_REQUIRED and ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE  will make all the transactions created from another thread, <b>WAIT</b> if already a transaction with same definition is running? well if i want to achieve it what needs to tweaked?

Comment: Works for me for `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` with Spring 3.2.13. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Support for custom isolation level was added in Spring 4.1.2 to [EclipseLinkJpaDialect](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/EclipseLinkJpaDialect.java#L77)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer

"To achieve serializable transaction isolation with EclipseLink, we recommend that you use an isolated client session as follows:

Configure the database transaction isolation as serializable.
Configure objects as isolated (see Configuring Cache Isolation at the Project Level or Configuring Cache Isolation at the Descriptor Level).
Use the UnitOfWork method beginTransactionEarly (see Unit of Work Method beginTransactionEarly).
If you are only concerned about the write aspect of serializable, optimistic locking is sufficient."

at http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/OTLCG/cache.htm or go through 
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/OTLCG/cache.htm
if any of isolation level meets your requirement